# Heroku not picking up autoprefixer config settings

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, autoprefixer

I'm deploying to Heroku and having issues with Heroku not picking up settings in my config/autoprefixer.yml file. When I precompile the assets locally, it works. But when the assets are compiled during slug compilation, only the default autoprefixer settings are in effect.

Am I missing something here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's the response I got from Heroku support which fixed the problem:

> This could be a caching issue during slug compilation. Assets are only
>   compiled if the source file has changed, otherwise sprockets will
>   reuse the previously compiled files. To rule this out, can you purge
>   the dyno cache by installing https://github.com/heroku/heroku-repo and
>   running heroku repo:purge_cache -a appname, then redeploy your
>   application with assets set to precompile.